# Git advice developing on windows hosting on linux

Tags: linux, git

git clone the windows into the linux window clones

Comment: The config files can be added to .gitignore, so that changes you make when developing will not be pushed to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*When I clone does it take all the files?* 
`YES. It copies all files, but except the files under '.git' folder.`

In GIT, there are many ways you can ignore specific files.

One of them is adding them to `.gitignore` file. But already tracked files will not be ignored.

As you've mentioned that you want to go beck to the previous versions of those files, you can not add them to `.gitignore`.

To ignore a tracked file only in your local machine, not in central repo:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged  <filename>
```

At any time, you can track again by setting --no-assume-unchaged flag

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged  <filename>
```

These command do not affect the remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you clone you're creating a separate repository on your localhost. An easy way for you to do what you want to do is create a repository on GitHub, add remotes to repositories on both your localhost and your server, and push/fetch as required.